# Sending SMS in Linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, notifications, sms

How can we send a SMS message from a Linux server to mobile for notifying  specific process status saying when a process goes down?

Comment: Something like [TextBelt](http://textbelt.com/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, it might help anyway. Point is that SMS and email work together in very similar ways. You can email a phone number and it will be received as a text.

Comment: @HalosGhost You can email *some* phone numbers, not all! Not all carriers are supported (in particular, Cricket)

Comment: @barrycarter, good to know. If that's the case though, those carriers are awful :P

Comment: @HalosGhost Noooooo, I love Cricket-- it's textbelt.com that sucks. You can use IFTTT and real SMS senders to send to ANY phone!